# Trouble writing my own Kmeans clustering function

Tags: r, for-loop, k-means

I am writing a simple function in R using for loop. The function takes a dataset , inside for loop, it loops through and provides different values for number of clusters to kmeans function. Code is given below:

```
 s_kmeans <- function(fname){
       wss = NULL
       dataset <- read.csv(file=fname1,header = TRUE, sep = ",")
       for(i in 2:10)
       {
         results <- kmeans(dataset,i)
         wss[i] <- results$tot.withinss
       }
       x <- c(2:10)
       df <- data.frame(x,wss)
       g <- ggplot(df, aes(x))
       g <- g+geom_line(aes(y=wss), color="red")
}
```

Now if I run this code it gives an error:

```
Error in data.frame(x, wss) : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 9, 10
```

Actually I want results from number of clusters 2 to 10. My understanding is for loops runs 9 times and x vector also has 9 elements. I have modified the code as shown below:

```
 s_kmeans <- function(fname){
           wss = NULL
           dataset <- read.csv(file=fname1,header = TRUE, sep = ",")
           for(i in 2:10)
           {
             results <- kmeans(dataset,i)
             wss[i] <- results$tot.withinss
           }
           x <- c(1:10)
           print(wss)
           print(x)
           df <- data.frame(x,wss)
           g <- ggplot(df, aes(x))
           g <- g+geom_line(aes(y=wss), color="red")
    }
```

Now it doesn't give any error, but puts NA for first element of wss (total 10 elements in wss, should be 9 as for loop runs for 9 times) vector and x vector. Out is shown below:

```
[1]        NA 1019.0836  864.0937  655.6397  506.3810  520.0426  374.2550  294.3192  330.9977  316.5263
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
```

I have no idea what is happening. Anyone can please help.

Comment: Unrelated to the error, but the function parameter is `fname` but then you use `fname1` inside the function?

Comment: When `i == 2`, you assign a value to `wss[2]` - which makes `wss` a vector of length 2 with a missing first element. In your first code example, you could instead assign to `wss[i - 1] <- results$tot.withinss`.

Answer (score 1):

Cause you do not set value for wss[1], so it gave you NA. Try to modify your loop as below

```
for(i in 1:9)
{
    results <- kmeans(dataset,i+1)
    wss[i] <- results$tot.withinss
}
x <- c(1:9)
```

Comment: Actaully for graphing purposes x values should start from 2 as it indicates number of clusters, otherwise your logic looks fine. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is not with the k-means, you have a problem with the dimensions when you define your variables. What you want to do is to plot `x` vs. `tot.withinss` which is the number of clusters vs sum, and choose the best number so you must to do the next:

```
s_kmeans <- function(fname){
           wss = NULL
           dataset <- read.csv(file=fname1,header = TRUE, sep = ",")
           for(i in 2:10)
           {
             results <- kmeans(dataset,i)
             wss[(i-1)] <- results$tot.withinss
           }
           x <- 2:10
           print(wss)
           print(x)
           df <- data.frame(x,wss)
           g <- ggplot(df, aes(x))
           g <- g+geom_line(aes(y=wss), color="red")
    }
```

Look `x`starts from `2`as you want and `wss` will be a vector 9-dimensional, so your plot will have

```
> x
[1]  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
```

And the total sum of squares which is `tot.withinss`.